# Javascript Counter for Cumulative Hours

Tags: javascript, counter

We need to get a counter to work to show our cumulative hours but I can't seem to get it to go. It was working on an old site but I can't get it to work on the new one. Can anyone tell me if I am missing something important below?

**HTML (abbreviated):**

```
<html lang="en-US">
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div id="counter"></div>
    <script src="../js/counter.js" type="text/javascript">
  </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript File (counter.js):**

```
//update next three variables once per week using current fleet data
var START_DATE = new Date("February 17, 2015 23:59:00"); // the date and time when run hours were known
var START_VALUE = 316398; // the run hours known at the date above
var INCREMENT = 0.0055; // 4000 fleet hrs per week = .0066 per sec, how many fleet run hours are added every second of the day

var INTERVAL = 1; // in seconds
var count = 0;
var fleetyears = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
 var msInterval = INTERVAL * 1000;
 var now = new Date();
 count = parseInt((now - START_DATE)/msInterval) * INCREMENT + START_VALUE;
 fleetyears = count / 8766;

 document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = "&nbsp;Cumulative Fleet Runtime: " + Number(count.toFixed(2)).toLocaleString('en') + " hours (" + Number(fleetyears.toFixed(2)).toLocaleString('en') + " years)&nbsp;"; //simply 'count' if unformatted
 window.setInterval( function(){
  count += INCREMENT; 
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = "&nbsp;Cumulative Fleet Runtime: " + Number(count.toFixed(2)).toLocaleString('en') + " hours (" + Number(fleetyears.toFixed(2)).toLocaleString('en') + " years)&nbsp;"; //simply 'count' if unformatted
 }, msInterval);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work. The problem was that I was trying to get it to work in Wordpress. I can't use $ in wordpress so I had to replace it with jQuery:

```
//update next three variables once per week using current fleet data
var START_DATE = new Date("February 17, 2015 23:59:00"); // the date and time when run hours were known
var START_VALUE = 316398; // the run hours known at the date above
var INCREMENT = 0.0055; // 4000 fleet hrs per week = .0066 per sec, how many fleet run hours are added every second of the day

var INTERVAL = 1; // in seconds
var count = 0;
var fleetyears = 0;

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 var msInterval = INTERVAL * 1000;
 var now = new Date();
 count = parseInt((now - START_DATE)/msInterval) * INCREMENT + START_VALUE;
 fleetyears = count / 8766;

 document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = "&nbsp;Cumulative Fleet Runtime: " + Number(count.toFixed(2)).toLocaleString('en') + " hours (" + Number(fleetyears.toFixed(2)).toLocaleString('en') + " years)&nbsp;"; //simply 'count' if unformatted
 window.setInterval( function(){
  count += INCREMENT; 
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = "&nbsp;Cumulative Fleet Runtime: " + Number(count.toFixed(2)).toLocaleString('en') + " hours (" + Number(fleetyears.toFixed(2)).toLocaleString('en') + " years)&nbsp;"; //simply 'count' if unformatted
 }, msInterval);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**`$`** is undefined. I think you need to make sure jQuery is included before running your JS code. Perhaps you can update your HTML like:

```
<html lang="en-US">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="counter"></div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../js/counter.js" type="text/javascript">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like jquery is loaded in the header and I moved the call for the counter.js file to the very end of the file.

Comment: I just updated the home page with some text showing where the html code is:  <div id="counter"></div>